# Unable to use "from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer" , it shows the exception " Data must be 1-dimensional"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have made a model for the artificial neural network(ANN). I want to preprocess the data before train the model. 
I have tried the code given below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Update-Detaset with hacking1.csv')
y=[]
X = dataset.iloc[:,2:7]
y = dataset.iloc[:,8]
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
Y = np.reshape(y,(-1,1))
imputer = imputer.fit(Y)
Y= imputer.transform(Y)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Here, `Update-Detaset with hacking1.csv` is the .csv file. The dataset is lookig like:
[Please click the link to see the demo of the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuwuj.jpg)
 It shows the following errors.
How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you add complete traceback?

Comment: What is `dataset`?

Comment: @Kampi You may look it now. I have added the description of the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `Imputer`. You should have been able to tell this from the line number that threw the Exception. The error is from you trying to reshape a pandas `DataFrame`. Change

```
y = dataset.iloc[:,8]
```

to

```
y = dataset.iloc[:,8].values
```

and it should work.